# How to share Javascript class between multiple HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, class

I am trying to write html files that shares a single java-script class.

This class is defined in **start.html**

```
class ipReader {
      constructor(name, ip) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ip = ip;
      }
      display() {
        console.log('Reader:' + this.name + ' @ ' + this.ip);
      }
    }

var x = new ipReader('Reader01', '127.0.0.1');
x.display();
```

and I want to share this class to **end.html**.

I have tried sharing with **windows.localStorage** without luck.

It seems like localStorage only saves literally.

```
// start.html
    localStorage.setItem("class", x); 

// end.html
  var y = localStorage.getItem('class');
  y.display(); // RETURNS not-a-function error. "y" is literally "[object Object]"
  typeof y     // RETURNS "string"
```

Should I literally save every single variables and then re-create & initialize class every-time?

How should I properly share a class instance between html pages?

Comment: you can use an spa framework of some kind or yea, save POJOs and rebuild your class instances

Comment: You need to serialize (JSON.stringify()) and de-serialize (JSON.parse()) data between HTML pages.  Remember you can only serialize actual data, so methods (functions) won't be done automatically.  Each method you want to port over must also be converted (serialized) into strings.  I think your answer can be found here:  https://medium.com/@oprearocks/serializing-object-methods-using-es6-template-strings-and-eval-c77c894651f0

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I will have a look into POJO and serializing technique.